# Can timestamp have microseconds in AWS Forecast?

Tags: amazon-web-services, forecast, amazon-forecast

Is it valid to have timestamp data with microseconds in timestamp (AWS Forecast)? I defined format like this: *YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US*. Dataset import failed, so I think that timestamp can be a problem. Do I have to aggregate data myself to fit minimal frequency (1 minute)?

Answer (score 0):

'Minute(s)' that is the maximum granularity amazon-forecast supports for datasets at present.

see image below,

[image]